# I have a info window for every marker i have created ...now how to close one info window automatically by opening another

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap() {
             var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.178996,115.5241033);
             var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.178996,115.5241033);

             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
               zoom: 2,
               center: latLng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
             });

             var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.5, 92.75),
               draggable: false,
               raiseOnDrag: false,
               map: map,
               labelContent: "Andaman",
               labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
               labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label

             });

             var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.4293648, 114.0550177),
               draggable: false,
               raiseOnDrag: false,
               map: map,
               labelContent: "Borneo",
               labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
               labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label

             });


var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: "<div class='gm'>mycontent</div>"

             });
             var iw2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: "<div class='gm'>mycontent</div>"
             });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function (e) { iw2.open(map, this); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all of them in array and before opening a one window loop through your array and call close method of each of you infowindow.

So at the beginning of the code declare something like

```
myWindows = [];
```

whenever you create new infoWindow add it to this array, so in your code:

```
var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<div class='gm'>mycontent</div>"
});
myWindows.push(iW1);

var iw2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<div class='gm'>mycontent</div>"
});
myWindows.push(iw2);
```

and whenever you open new window instead of just

```
iw1.open();
```

you'll have to close all IWs (well you will just close one, but call `.close()` method on all of them) so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myWindows.length; ++i) {
    myWindows[i].close;
}
iw1.open();
```

Of course, you can create function for purpose of opening IWs, to make your life easier.

Comment: I am not tat good in script.. could you just state some examples

Comment: @user3699344 I've edited my answer to be more understandible, hope it helps (but you may consider MarkSetchell 's answer if it suits you better)

Answer (score 0):

Have a single re-usable InfoWindow, like this:

```
// One single re-useable InfoWindow
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for(id=0;id<tableids.length;id++){
    layers[id] = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        query: {
            select: 'col2',
            from: tableids[id],
        },
    });

        google.maps.event.addListener(layers[id], 'click', function(e) {
            windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
        });
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
// Open the info window at the clicked location
function windowControl(e, infoWindow, map) {

// Now build HTML we want in our InfoWindow
var HTML;
    HTML = "<div class='googft-info-window'>";
    HTML+= "<strong>Reference</strong>: " + Ref  + " ";
    HTML+= "<strong>Date</strong>: " + Date + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    HTML +="</div>";

    infoWindow.setOptions({
            content: HTML,
            position: e.latLng,
            pixelOffset: e.pixelOffset
    });
    infoWindow.open(map);
```

}